# Trying to print NSAttributedString via many UITextViews causes crash

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uitextview

My Mac app uses many `NSTextView`s just fine for printing a long string, but trying to do the same on iOS with many `UITextView`s and associated `UIViewPrintFormatter`s just causes a crash.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d03ab1 _CFThrowFormattedException + 194
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b83bf9 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 169
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48029503 -[UITextViewPrintFormatter rectForPageAtIndex:] + 86
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4806bc79 __57-[UIPrintPageRenderer drawPrintFormatter:forPageAtIndex:]_block_invoke + 41
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4806bcf9 __57-[UIPrintPageRenderer drawPrintFormatter:forPageAtIndex:]_block_invoke.43 + 29
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e4f6d48 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e505b24 _dispatch_async_and_wait_invoke + 175
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e4f6d48 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e504de6 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1500
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd4049 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bceca9 __CFRunLoopRun + 2329
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bce066 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff384c0bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48092d4d UIApplicationMain + 1621
    16  myApp                               0x000000010e1ca61b main + 75
    17  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5227ec25 start + 1
    18  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

Here's the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
        let printPageRenderer = PrintPageRenderer()
        printController.printPageRenderer = printPageRenderer
        printController.present(animated: true)
    }

}

class PrintPageRenderer: UIPrintPageRenderer {

    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(string: "fhdjksalhfj dskla fjf")
    var textViews = [UITextView]()

    override func prepare(forDrawingPages range: NSRange) {
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            for (i, textView) in textViews.enumerated() {
                let printFormatter = textView.viewPrintFormatter()
                addPrintFormatter(printFormatter, startingAtPageAt: i)
            }
        }
    }

    override var numberOfPages: Int {
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        let size = CGFloat(50)
        for _ in 0..<2 {
            let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize(width: size, height: size))
            layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
            let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size), textContainer: textContainer)
            textViews.append(textView)
        }
        return textViews.count
    }

}
```

My goal is printing a document from an attributed string and showing a custom header and footer on each page.

Comment: Have you looked into using a `PDFView` instead?

Comment: No, I never used this class before. Why do you think it would be a better approach?

Comment: I haven't used it either, but maybe it is more useful for printing instead of a `UITextView`. Worth looking into.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I'm more interested in knowing why my approach doesn't work.